# moving an array in a circular way

Tags: python, arrays, list, numbers

I tried to write a programe that gets a list and a number 'N' of steps from the user. The programe will move in a circular way the list. If the number is positive the items in the list will move N steps left, and if N is negative the items will move N steps right. If N=0 the list won't change.

```
L=[1,2,3,4,5]
if N==0  > [1,2,3,4,5]
if N==1  > [2,3,4,5,1]
if N==-1 > [5,1,2,3,4]
```

Can someone give me a clue how to code this program?

Comment: so basically rotate the array? you just need some appropriate pop/shift-type operations.

Comment: you should look up slicing in python. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: It does the same thing for N=1 & N=-1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using slices:

```
def shift(array, n):
    return array[n:] + array[:n]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) and negate `n` if you want to reverse the logic:

```
from collections import deque

deq = deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
n = 0
deq.rotate(-n)
print(deq)

deq = deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
n = 1
deq.rotate(-n)
print(deq)

deq = deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
n = -1
deq.rotate(-n)
print(deq)
```

Output:

```
deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
deque([2, 3, 4, 5, 1])
deque([5, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

`n` can be larger than the number of elements and rotate will still work:

```
In [5]: deq = deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [6]: deq.rotate(12)

In [7]: deq
Out[7]: deque([4, 5, 1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Since rotating a deque changes the order of the deque itself I would addtionally recommend writing a own function where to pass a list in and convert this list into a deque. Then rotate the deque and return it. So the original data order is kept unchanged. If needed you can convert the deque into a list before returning.

Comment: @albert, if a list is passed in the original list is not going to change, unless the OP needs some list specific behaviour then they should use a deques from the get go.

Comment: This is much more complicated than slicing.  See pp_'s answer and mine.

Comment: In what way does it not work properly?

Comment: The question has changed since I posted my answer.  I also don't think that insults will improve anything.  In my comment, I did not mean to be derogatory.  If I was, than I am sincerely sorry.  I have deleted my answer, because I now believe that it is not helpful.